# WCF with multiple http hostnames

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I get this:

> This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.

whenever I try to access my WCF service... we have two host names set up so we can hit our domain from http://www.mydomain.com and http://mydomain.com but the error says you can only have one address. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant config on the server side?? Also: do you host this in IIS, or do you self-host (in a Windows NT Service or something)?

Comment: This is in IIS, not sure what part of the Web.config would be important... '<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MySite.services.EmployeeInfoBehavior"
        name="MySite.services.EmployeeInfo">
        <endpoint address="http://midvalecity.org/services/EmployeeInfo.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MySite.services.IEmployeeInfo">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>'

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.robzelt.com/blog/2007/01/24/WCF+This+Collection+Already+Contains+An+Address+With+Scheme+Http.aspx) should solve your issue.